# Change "Enter your answer" text in Microsoft Forms input fields

Tags: sharepoint-online

Is it possible to change the standard text in the text fields in a MS Forms form.

I created a form in MS Forms and all the input text fields have the text "Enter your answer" text in them when nothing has been typed.
Can I change this text? 
And also the text in the Submit button, I would like it to say Send instead of Submit.

Eg. I have a name field, it would be nice if it said "Enter your name" instead

I'm using SharePoint Online

My first post here, so let me know if you need additional information

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is by design in Microsoft Forms, we can't modify it in currently.

Check the user voice with same issue here: [edit placeholder-text](https://microsoftforms.uservoice.com/forums/386451-welcome-to-microsoft-forms-suggestion-box/suggestions/31801840-edit-placeholder-text)

[image]